# Conditional summarizing via inject

Tags: ruby, code-injection, enumerable

How to get the index of item in:

```
my_array.inject {|rs,item| rs += item}
```

I need to summarize all except the i-th element.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just summarize over the indices.

```
(0...a.size).inject(0) { |sum, index| if index != (i - 1) then sum + my_array[i] else sum }
```

Comment: Thanks, but it looks like there's simpler way:
my_arr.inject {|rs,item| rs += item if my_arr.index(item)!= 0}

Comment: But the simpler way you suggested is dangerous with duplicate items and much less performant - Element lookup requires O(n).

Answer (score 3):

You would have to write your own (even in Ruby 1.9, since inject does not return an iterator).

```
module Enumerable
  def inject_with_index(injected)
    each_with_index {|value, index| injected = yield(injected, value, index)}
    injected
  end
end
```

Edit: If you switch `inject` and `each_with_index` around (thanks to the commenter!) you can do it without a new method:

```
["a", "b", "c"].each_with_index.inject("") do |result, (value, index)|
  index != 1 ? result + value : result
end
```

Make sure to return just `result` if you want to exclude the value. This also applies to the first method.

Comment: You're right, I didn't think of switching both. But you have to put the arguments in parentheses.

Answer (score 2):

use `index` method of array:

```
>> arr = ['a','b', 'c','a']
=> ["a", "b", "c", "a"]
>> arr.index('a')
=> 0
>> arr.index('b')
=> 1
```

Answer (score 2):

You could take out the item you don't want first:

```
my_array.values_at(0...i,(i+1)..-1).inject {|rs,item| rs += item}
```